# Win RT Phone 8.1 Application: Clear page cache only if internet is working on mobile

Tags: caching, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have applied cache in my application as describe in [this blog](http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/) but I don't want to clear cache of page while navigating back.

What I want is that if user navigate to that page check internet and then if internet is working clear the cache and make service call and show and save that data in cache again and if internet is not working then show the cached data and don't make internet call. Sharing my peice of code so that you can understand clearly what I'm trying to do.

**Page load event:**

```
        void ProfilePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Helper.IsConnectedToInternet())
        {
            ResetPageCache();
            GetData();
        }
        else
        {
            ContentText.Text = App.GetResource("NoInternetAlert");
            AlertMessage.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

When I navigate to this page and after that I have a page to add phone number, Navigate to this page, turn off WIFI and navigate back, it will run else code snippet and shows no internet alert. From overall behaviour it seems like once I ran `ResetPageCache()` it deletes cache and don't save the new data. My `ResetCacheFunction` is little different from the blog link because of some changes in version I think so pasting that function below but functionality is same:

```
private void ResetPageCache()
    {
        if (this.Frame == null) { return; }

        var cacheSize = this.Frame.CacheSize;
        this.Frame.CacheSize = 0;
        this.Frame.CacheSize = cacheSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I would think that you forgot to write the follwing code your `ProfilePage` constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

which caches the actual page when you navigate back to it.

Comment: instead of required I wrote Enable, because that blog said that setting mode to required will not delete cache. However I have solved the problem and that was not the Cache problem :( Will soon paste my solution in answer

Answer (score 0):

That was not the problem of cache, inside my `getdata()` I was doing this

```
if (!defaultViewModel.ContainsKey("ProfileData"))
            {
                defaultViewModel.Add("ProfileData", ProfileData.Result);
            }
```

After much debugging I understand that cache was saving the defaultviewmodel and after making new call it still shows the previous data so I change it to this

```
if (!defaultViewModel.ContainsKey("ProfileData"))
            {
                defaultViewModel.Add("ProfileData", ProfileData.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                defaultViewModel.Remove("ProfileData");
                defaultViewModel.Add("ProfileData", ProfileData.Result);
            }
```

And it starts working